# Will Azure DevOps or another Azure service allow my team to run my python code?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have a python script which utilizes the pyqt5 gui and the Azure DevOps python library to read through ADO work items and create a PowerPoint doc (pptx) on the local machine by downloading attachments of the user-specified ADO work items.

I'd like anyone on my team to be able to run this code (preferably without much technical expertise), they all have access to the ADO project but no one else has a Personal Access Token. Is this possible through ADO or another Azure service? Can I avoid the PAT requirement for my teammates by using AKV?

I've never done something like this before and haven't really been able to find a clear path forward.

Comment: Did you look into managed identity options? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-service-principal-and-managed-identity-support-on-azure-devops/

Answer (score 1):

There is good documentation regarding this - [Choose the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops)

As far as I see you need to combine [Service Principal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-service-principal-and-managed-identity-support-on-azure-devops/), [MSL for python](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#scenarios) and [interactive flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/1.11.0/sample/interactive_sample.py).

> [For a desktop app to call a web API that signs in users, use the interactive token-acquisition methods of MSAL. With these interactive methods, you can control the sign-in UI experience. MSAL uses a web browser for this interaction.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#desktop-app-that-calls-a-web-api-on-behalf-of-a-signed-in-user)